# Typescript return value

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to return a string from a typescript function -

```
private _renderListAsync(): string {
  let _accHtml: string='';
    // Local environment
    if (Environment.type === EnvironmentType.Local) {      

      this._getMockListData()
      .then((response) => {
        _accHtml = this._renderList(response.value);
        alert("1: " + _accHtml)
        })
        alert("3: " + _accHtml);
        return _accHtml;
    }
    else if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
              Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {

      this._getListData()
        .then((response) => {
          _accHtml = this._renderList(response.value);
          alert("2: " + _accHtml);          
        })      
        alert("3: " + _accHtml);
        return _accHtml;
    }       
  }
```

However, I am only able to get the string value for alerts with "1" and "2" but not "3" where the alert is empty, hence I am not able to return _accHtml from the function. What am I doing wrong? Also I notice that alert with "3" shows up before "1" and "2", why is that?

Comment: I have also tried returning _accHtml after the if-else blocks, still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I'm seeing some indicators of the promise API (i.e. `.then()` which may signal that you're using async calls. This feels like an async issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because ".then(...)" is a process asynchronous,it opens new thread, and continues execute next lines of the method, it shows 3 before 2 and 1. I recomend that use Observables